# Does a disabled person have to pay Zakat or can he/she be exempt?

Tags: zakat, disability

What is the criteria for Zakat for a disabled person who is in terminal illness. The person lives from her/his savings, which are used for medicine and caretaker but his/her savings (which is used day by day for treatment) are above Nisab. Someone please put the light on this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Every Muslim who owns wealth above nisab for a whole lunar year is obliged to pay Zakat on it, there are no exceptions there is no evidence of any admissible excuses. If this is a long term issue maybe you should consider investing to create an income stream.